# Write a character array with null values into a file stream

Tags: c++, null, stream

I am new to c++ and am still figuring out file streams. I am trying to put a character array into a file that I will be viewing with a hex editor.

I have done different strings, but whenever I put in a null byte, the file ends.

```
ofstream stream;
char charArray[256];
for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)charArray[i] = i;
stream.open("C:\\testfile.myimg");
if (!stream.is_open()) exit(1);
stream << charArray << endl;
return 0;
```

I want to output bytes with ascending values, but if I start with the null byte, then c++ thinks the character array ends before it starts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
stream << charArray << endl;
```

use:

```
stream.write(charArray, sizeof(charArray));
stream.write("\n", 1);  // this is the newline part of std::endl
stream.flush();         // this is the flush part of std::endl
```

The first one assumes that you are sending a *null-terminated* string (because you're passing a `char*` - see the end of the answer why). That's why when the code encounters the very first `char` with value `0`, which is `'\0'` (the null-terminator), it stops.

On the other hand, the second approach uses an unformatted output write, which will not care about the values inside `charArray` - it will take it (as a pointer to its first element) and write `sizeof(charArray)` **bytes** starting from that pointer to the `stream`. This is safe since it's guaranteed that `sizeof(char) == 1`, thus `sizeof(charArray)` will yield `256`.

What you need to consider is *array decaying*. It will work in this case (the `sizeof` thing), but it will not work if you simply pass a decayed pointer to the array's first element. Read more here: [what's array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: You should also open the file in `binary` mode when writing raw data to it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I totally see why that would be a logical assumption, but I'm struggling to actually find sources saying that it won't work without opening in binary mode. Would you please provide a standard section regarding this very case or some other, reliable source?